# Dynamic Polymorphic Memory Container - Return Value Incorrect

Tags: c++, templates, memory

I am currently working on an dynamic memory container.

Basic idea of the class is that you should be able to get the iterator of an object if you really do not know it, without the use of a for loop throughout all the elements to boost performance. The issue I have is the following; when you pass your pointer address to the object you want to get the iterator of it type casts the object into the extended memory containers structures type. This type contains an extra element, an integer. (IteratorNum)

When following the code the integer within the function is set to correct value, as below would be 50. But when the returned value is set into the local integer used in the main function it is 200? I've been adding watches and cannot figure out how it is possible that the function returns 50 but value gets set to 200.

```
template <typename DataType> class MemoryContainer {
public:
    struct LevelData : DataType
    {
        int element;
    };
    DataType &New()
    {
        elements++;
        //Reallocate the size of the array
        ld   = (LevelData*)realloc(ld, sizeof(LevelData) * elements);
        //Set the iteratorNumber
        ld[elements - 1].element = elements - 1;

        return ld[elements - 1];
    }
    DataType *reserve(int num)
    {
        return calloc(num, sizeof(DataType));
    }
    DataType &operator[](int i)
    {
        return ld[i];
    }
    bool inArray(DataType *type)
    {
        //Compare memory addresses and see if it's within.
        return (type >= &ld[0]) && (type < &ld[elements - 1]);
    }

    static unsigned int getIterator(DataType *type)
    {
        //                   v this is 50, but in main says returns 200.
        return ((LevelData*)type)->element;
    }
    MemoryContainer()
    {
        elements = 0;
    }
    ~MemoryContainer()
    {
        free(data);
    }
private:
    unsigned int elements;
    LevelData *ld;
};

struct Effective
{
    //Set it to polymorphic classes
    virtual void dummy()
    {

    }

    char * testvar;
    Effective(char * c)
    {
        testvar = c;
    }
    Effective(){}
};
MemoryContainer<Effective> myContainer;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Create 200 elements in the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        myContainer.New().testvar = "E";

    //Add pointer for testing purposes to get the iterator.
    Effective * pointer = &myContainer[50];

    //Test setting it's value
    pointer->testvar = "HEHEHE";

    //Get iterator of our pointer in the array
    unsigned int i = myContainer.getIterator(pointer);

    printf(pointer->testvar);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `free(data);` - undefined identifier "data". You may want to fix that.

Comment: If you do a tab-to-space conversion on your code, it'll be more readable....

Comment: You know you constructors and destructors (implicit or otherwise) for `Effective` and `DataType` won't fire, right? Don't miss C++ objects with malloc/realloc/free unless you *seriously* know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for that one @WhozCraig, was an old thing that was deleted for this post. Yet the problem remains, the unsigned int i inside the main function is set to 200 but the function returns 50.

Comment: @WhozCraig I do know that, do not worry about so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is the visual studio debugger getting confused between your two `i` variables. If you print out the value of `i`, it will print correctly. If you change the name of your variable to something else, the value shows as 50 in the debugger.

That said, your code is a mish-mash of c and c++ and won't work correctly with anything that requires a copy constructor. I would suggest at the very least using `new []` rather than `realloc`.

Also, any user of this collection who tries to store a class with a member variable called `element` is going to get mighty confused.

Answer (score 1):

The unsigned int i in the main function really has a value of 50, but the debugger is confusing it with the i declared in the for loop (I reproduced this with Visual Studio 2013). If you cout i it will be 50, and if you change the variable name it will show up as 50 in the debugger. I've never seen this problem before so I wonder if it might be due to your use of malloc/realloc/free with C++ objects.

Comment: Good thought, but VS still gets it wrong if you take out everything except the for loop (with a simple `x+=i;` in it) and an `i = 50`. Also, if you look in the "locals" tab in the debugger you can see both `i`s. I suspect being able to see the out of scope `i` is there so you can see what the last value of `i` was when the for loop finished.

Comment: Yep, I see that now. So it's just the Autos window showing the wrong i.